# Nullable Types in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Can Nullable Types be used in VB.NET?  If so, is it possible to have a Nullable Integer that I can use with a field that accepts NULL in SQL Server?  Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Nullable types can be used in VB.NET same as in C#.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types)

You can't assign `Null`, `Nothing` or `DBNull` to a bare `Integer` in VB but you *can* use a [`Nullable(Of Integer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead:

```vb
Dim x As Integer? = Nothing
```

Alternatively, it sometimes (but rarely) makes sense to box the integer value in an `Object` (which can be `Nothing`).

Comment: in fact, you can assign Nothing to an integer in VB.NET: 
`Dim a As Integer = Nothing`

But after that, following is true:
`a = 0`

Comment: To clarify that, `Nothing` in VB.NET is like `default(T)` in C#. It behaves differently when used with value or reference types.

Answer (score 60):

VB.Net does have nullable types, they can be declared in the following two different ways.

```
Dim iNullable As Integer?
```

or

```
Dim iNullable As Nullable(Of Integer)
```

Comment: Actually there are [3 ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx): Dim iNullable? as Integer

Comment: 4 ways: dim x%?

Answer (score 7):

Integers (`System.Int32` etc) in .NET are not directly nullable; however, there is [`Nullable-of-T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) that allows you to make any value-type nullable-ish. Note that you may have to check the database against `DBNull` rather than `null`/`Nothing`.

So yes, you can do something very similar.

Answer (score 4):

In a number of cases `Nothing` will get converted to the default value. To use `Nothing` the same way you would use `null` you need to cast it to the correct nullable type.

```
Dim str As String
Dim int As Nullable(Of Integer) ' or use As Integer?
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim colA As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("colA")
Dim colB As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("colB")
str = If(reader.IsDBNull(colA), DirectCast(Nothing, String), reader.GetString(colA))
int = If(reader.IsDBNull(colB), DirectCast(Nothing, Nullable(Of Integer)), reader.GetInt32(colB))
```

Answer (score 2):

Only way I know to enter NULL's into db from client code (as asked in comments below question) is to use default values in SQL equal to NULL.

So in Update/Insert stored procedure you can use something like:

```sql
create proc dbo.UpdateSomeTable
    @Id int, 
    @Status bit = NULL
as
begin
    update dbo.SomeTable
    set Status = @Status
    where Id = @Id
end
```

and somewhere in code

```vb
Dim pars As List(Of SqlParameter) = New List(Of SqlParameter)
With pars
    .Add(New SqlParameter("@Id", LogbookNoteId))
    If Flag Then
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@Status", Flag))
    End If
End With
ExecuteNonQuery("dbo.UpdateSomeTable", pars, CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  You will have to modify the insert or update query to not add (or update) that value to get a null in the database.