# How do you define a Nullable Type Property in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, types

How would you define a Nullable type property in Visual Basic. 
How can I leverage the HasValue propterty in the Setter ?

Thanks.

Comment: `Public Property Bar As Nullable(Of Integer)` or `Public Property Foo As Integer?`

Comment: Google `How do you define a Nullable Type Property in Visual Basic` and click the **first** result: [Nullable Value Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx).

Comment: @plutonix as Integer?

Comment: yes - the question mark is short hand for Nullable.  You will see it in Intellisense that way when using Nullables...  `Dim foo as Int32?`

Comment: Duplicate of [Nullable Types in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123844/nullable-types-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the `HasValue` in the setter, unless I'm not understanding your question.  Here is an example:

```
Private _myValue As Integer?

Public Property MyValue As Integer?
    Get
        Return _myValue
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer?)
        _myValue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Since both `value` and `_myValue` are of type `Integer?` (i.e. "nullable" `Integer`), they will match on type.

Of course, if you have just a plain old getter/setter property with no logic (e.g. lazy loading), it's easier to use an auto-implemented property, like this:

```
Public Property MyValue As Integer?
```

i.e. with no explicitly declared backing field (`Private _myValue As Integer?`).

Comment: Can this be enhanced to check if value.HasValue and then set the setter.

Comment: My point is the backing field itself *is* a nullable type, so you can set the backing field's value without worrying about `value.HasValue`.  I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry My bad. Let me add this... what if this field were a database field with a null in it and it hasn't been set yet, or will be set in the future.

Comment: @JeffJaffery -- Then you would check that before you even assign it to the property, from outside the class.  I would use a ternary "if" statement like `MyClassObject.MyValue = If(Not row.IsNull("MyDBColumn"), CInt(row.Item("MyDBColumn")), New Integer?)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Basic [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types) says you can define a *nullable* property in three ways:

```
Dim ridesBusToWork1? As Boolean
Dim ridesBusToWork2 As Boolean?
Dim ridesBusToWork3 As Nullable(Of Boolean)
```

Comment: These are not properties, these are local variables. its said "You can write the declaration in three ways:"