# Insert a row in a table based on the returned quantity of a function

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a function that returns a count. Using this returned count, I want to insert a new row into an SQL table for each qty returned from the function.

Here is a sample of what I started with:

```
compcount = ems.getparentcountfromorder(row("ordernumber"))

Dim count As Object = compcount

For Each i As Object In count
      connection.executesql("INSERT INTO composite_pick_ID (parentprodid, ordernumber) VALUES('" & row("productid") & "','" & row("ordernumber") & "')")
      count = count - 1
Next
```

I would like my end result to be something like this:

- `If count = 2`, then I want 2 rows inserted into `composite_pick_ID`.

Comment: What happen now? And why converting everything to object? What is the type of compcount?

Comment: We were setting compcount as an integer, as far as making them objects, I wasn't able to iterate through count when it was an integer and didn't know how to do so.

Comment: Just `for i = 0 to compcount-1` with `Dim compcount as Integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ems.getparentcountfromorder(row("ordernumber"))` is coded for a return from SQL, dimension `count` as a Nullable integer to handle when SQL returns Null as a Query Result.

```
Dim count as Nullable(of Integer) = ems.getparentcountfromorder(row("ordernumber"))
'or in shorthand
Dim count as integer? = ems.getparentcountfromorder(row("ordernumber"))

If count.HasValue then
 For i as Integer = 1 to count
   connection.executesql('my insert statement')
 Next
End if
```

More on Nullable Type in VB here: [Nullable Types in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123844/nullable-types-in-vb-net?answertab=votes#tab-top)