# Why in the conditionnal "if" assignement do not assign nothing/null value to a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I was surprised when I tried to assign null value to a variable using ternary expression in vb.net. When I assign through ternary expression, it doesn't works as expected.

```vb
Dim i As Integer? = Nothing
Dim j As Integer? = Nothing
i = If(True, j, 1)
j = If(True, Nothing, 1)
```

After execution of this code: i is nothing but j becomes 0 (zero). Why?
What is the explanation?
Why I can"t assign directly Nothing (Null) value?

Comment: Good spot. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/vHDdkk, taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378158/1086121 in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: The answer [appears to be in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378158/424129) to David's suggested duplicate: You have to explicitly cast `Integer? j` to `Integer?`, or else its value of `Nothing` will automatically be converted to the default value of `Integer`.

Comment: To get what you expect change the j = to j = If(True, New Integer?, 1)

Answer (score 4):

I think the important thing to understand here is **`Nothing` in VB.Net is not the same as `null` in other languages**, because you can still assign `Nothing` to value types. In many other languages, `null` is a reference-type construct only. If you're familiar with C#, `Nothing` is closer to `default(T)` than to `null`.

With that in mind, take a fresh look at this expression:

```
If(True, Nothing, 1)
```

The compiler evaluates the entire expression on it's own merits, knowing nothing about `i` or `j`, even though `j` is the target of the assignment. The expression has to be able to stand alone.

VB.Net must also determine a type to use for the expression, and it must do this at compile-time. It is not able to infer anything from the use of `Nothing` about needing an `Integer?` rather than a basic non-nullable `Integer` for this type, because VB.Net is perfectly happy to assign `Nothing` to value types. Therefore the type of the conditional expression can only be inferred from the `1` literal in the final argument, which is a plain `Integer`, and not `Integer?`.

Given that resulting type, we now must evaluate `Nothing` as an integer, where the result is the `0` you observed. In theory, this part is done at runtime rather than compile time, but in practice I suspect the compiler or jitter recognizes the chance to optimize things and rewrites it all down to just `j = 0`.

If you want to be able to assign an `Integer?` with a value of `Nothing`, do it as you did in the first example and keep a variable handy with the correct type you can use for the assignment.

Comment: It's not "closer to" `default(T)`, it literally is `default(T)`.  See #46 here: https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/